# len() return incorrect value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
print(len(str(0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100)))
```

and this return 22.
However when I have this code:

```
print(len("0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100"))
```

this return 53.
Why?

Comment: Have you checked what `str(0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100)` is?

Comment: You created a float object; this is *not a string*. The string representation for that float object doesn't include as many digits because floating point values are an approximation and there simply isn't the precision there to capture the value *exactly*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python isn't able to store infinite precision floating-point numbers. They are truncated after a certain value. To learn more, you can [check out the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

```
str(0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100)
```

First python will interpret *0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100* as a floating number, then convert it to a string.

It turns out, `0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100` is interpreted as `0.00011001100110011001`, which is then cast as a string of 22 characters.